# jqGrid: How to add a cancel icon to jqGrid and capture the cancel event?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqGrid version 4.4.0.

1. How can I add a cancel icon to the title area in the upper right corner of my jqGrid?
2. How can I capture the cancel event when a user clicks this button once #1 above is done.

The standard grid comes with a collapse icon.  I was able to hide that using the attribute hidegrid:true, this seems to hide the collapse button which is a start, but I'm not sure how to wire up the rest.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "cancel icon? What are you trying to cancel?